# Django Auth permissions ignore model's app_label set in Meta

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

**Problem:** admin doesn't grant access to a model. I suspect the cause is a manually set `app_label` on the model.

I have a module with overridden `app_label` and `db_table` in their `Meta` class.

```
class FAQ(models.Model):
    # some fields
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'support'
        table_name = 'faq_faq'
```

This is what I could figure out:

**1.** When trying to give a user permissions to it, I see in the lists that for this model, instead of the usual format `<app_label> | <model> | <perm>` it doesn't show the `app_label` that was set in `Meta` but the model name itself, e.g. `faq | faq | Add..` and so on.

**2.** The `ModelBackend` class where the actual checking of permissions is happening seems to pick up the `app_label` from the `Permission` instance property `content_type`.

```
# django/contrib/auth/backends.py
user_obj._perm_cache = set(["%s.%s" % (p.content_type.app_label,
    p.codename) for p in user_obj.user_permissions.select_related()])
```

As it turns out, `Permission.content_type.app_label` is the same attribute used to populate the perms lists in **1.**, already noted to be different from the label set in the model. Since the `has_module_perms` **is** indeed called with the correct `_meta.app_label` model instance attribute, the expected app label in the permissions list isn't there and thus, the user isn't granted access.

To complicate matters more, I have several other models with the same setup (manually set `app_label` etc.) and they show up just fine on the user's detail page. They display the correct app label on the list, and giving the user access to these makes the admin show the links on the index page.

**Question:** while this seems like a bug, I'm aware that this is an uncommon scenario and I'm working on an unsupported version; can I work around this to force the permissions to recognize my own `app_label`?

**Environment:** django 1.6.1 (yes, EOL), django-suit 0.2.12

Many thanks in advance. Although I'd prefer a solution that didn't involve messing with the database (shuffling data around, recreating tables/models, etc), I also appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: Did you change the `app_label` after the model and the permission were created in the database?

Comment: @Alasdair I can't say for sure, but as far as `git blame` will let me know, both the migration and the model entered on the same commit, and haven't been touched since then. So I'd say no, they haven't been modified. Thank you.